# Configure Django model form with jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have three models :

```
    class Instances(models.Model):
        name_of_instances = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        url_of_instances=models.URLField(max_length=255,default='')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name_of_instances



    class Projects(models.Model):
        name_of_instances = models.ForeignKey(Instances,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name_of_jproject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        project_id= models.CharField(max_length=25)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name_of_project



    class All(models.Model):
        choices_instance=Instances.objects.all()
        b = [str(i.name_of_instances) for i in choices_instance]
        a=[str(i.url_of_instances) for i in choices_instance]
        choices_instance=tuple(zip(a,b))



        name = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=choices_instance)
        project = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
        story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        depends_on = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
        rfc = models.CharField(max_length=255)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

I have a models form:

```
    class Form(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = All
            fields =('name','project','story','depends_on','rfc')
```

In template, I want to know what user has drop down in 'name' field , and I want to send the name value to back end function where I will filter out all the projects associated with name value, and send the result to 'project' field as choices (drop down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution using java script and ajax on the template